# This is the first post of the series / This is the first post in the series

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, word-order

When writing a series in a blog, with which of the following sentences could you start the first sentence? Are they all correct, is only one correct, are there semantic or only aesthetic differences?
'...' = the title of the series

1. This is the first post of the '...' series.
2. This is the first post in the '...' series.
3. This is the first post of the series '...'.
4. This is the first post in the series '...'.

Comment: In part, it will depend on what is going in the *'...'* - if it's a single word, version 1 or 2 might do; but if it's a phrase ("... in the series about places to go on holiday") then you need version 3 or 4.

Answer (score 1):

> This is the first post of the '...' series.
>
> This is the first post in the '...' series.
>
> This is the first post of the series '...'.
>
> This is the first post in the series '...'.

All four are acceptable, but note TrevorD's comment above. The differences are mainly aesthetic. If the "..." is a phrase, you would technically need to hyphenate the phrase in the first two examples but not in the last two. For instance,

> "This is the first post in the going-to-the-market series."

versus

> "This is the first post in the series, 'Going to the Market.'"

Note also that if it is a phrase, you may wish to set it off with a comma and quotation marks, as I have done in the second example, using capitalization to make it more formally the title of the series. My personal preference is for "in" rather than "of," but that is just a matter of taste, not a rule.